# I got errors with gcc and ./install

Tags: gcc, linux-headers, droidcam

I'm triying to download and install droidcam from  https://www.dev47apps.com/droidcam/linux page oficial

```
gcc make linux-headers-`uname -r`    
cd /tmp/
wget https://files.dev47apps.net/linux/droidcam_latest.zip
echo "73db3a4c0f52a285b6ac1f8c43d5b4c7 droidcam_latest.zip" | md5sum -c --
unzip droidcam_latest.zip -d droidcam && cd droidcam
sudo ./install
```

but there's some errors:
the first with

````
gcc make linux-headers-`uname -r
gcc: error: make: No such file or directory
gcc: error: linux-headers-5.4.0-45-generic: No such file or directory```
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
````

And the second one when I type `sudo ./install` in droidcam folder. I get:

```
sudo ./install
[sudo] password for pc: 
Webcam parameters: '640' and '480'
Building v4l2loopback-dc.ko
./install: line 15: make: command not found
```

### I hope you can help me, need for the zoom meetings in class, very thanks!

Edit: I have installed the Linux-headers and I try with `sudo depmod`

Answer (score 2):

The line

```
gcc make linux-headers-`uname -r`
```

in step 1 of [the installation instructions](https://www.dev47apps.com/droidcam/linux/) is not a command - it's a list of dependencies (packages) that you are meant to install before the following steps, i.e.

```
sudo apt install gcc make linux-headers-`uname -r`
```